# Using data from PHP POST request (Laravel)

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have the following post request in my controller:

```
    public function CustomerCase($id)
  {
    $case = rental_request::with(['caseworker','user'])->where(['id'=>$id])->first();

    $url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/priceByLocation';
    $data = array('rentalObject' =>$case->attributesToArray());

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }

    return view("case", ['case'=>$case, 'apiResult' => $result]);
}
```

The post request returns the following JSON:

[image]

Now in my view, I wish to access this data so what I did was the following:

```
@if($apiResult)
          {{$apiResult->zipValues}}
@else
      Not found
@endif
```

However here I get the following error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

What have I done wrong?

**Using json_decode**:

```
return view("case", ['case'=>$case, 'apiResult' => json_decode($result)]);
```

If I attempt to use json_decode I get the following error:

[image]

### Solution

I made it work with the `json_decode` - it was because I was trying to get the root object and not a value from the object.

Comment: @ADyson i have attempted to use json_decode however i get a new error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `$apiResult` is a string, not an object. You never decoded the JSON in your controller, just passed it on into the variable directly.

Just inject the string directly into the Javascript and let your JS code get the properties it wants within that, i.e. just write

```
{{$apiResult}}
```

(I assume you're assigning the output of that as a JS variable.)

Alternatively, in your controller do

```
'apiResult' => json_decode($result)
```

inside your return statement to convert it to an object.

Comment: what did you do, out of interest? I think my first suggestion would get round the encoding issue.

Comment: i have updated my question basically i was attempting to get the root object and not a value from it

Answer (score 0):

Your `$result` is json. which means it is string not object/array. So you need to convert it. Use `json_decode()` to convert json string. so after result add json decode statement

```
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$result = json_decode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot display object or string on view you have to json_decode 
after json_decode you will get your object or array.
note when you {{}} means the value is a string / number / boolean etc

in your controller

```
return view('your-view')
->withApiResult(json_decode($result);
```

then you will get objct or array

use @foreach to loop through the data and display the value you want to display

```
@foreach(cols as col)
   display data
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are trying to print an object, note that `$apiResult->zipValues` is an object, use `json_decode($result, true)` to transform json to array and then print all values using blade foreach

**controller**

```
'apiResult' => json_decode($result, true)
```

**View**

```
@foreach($apiResult['zipValues'] as $value)
    {{ $value }}
@endforeach
```